# Why did all my files turn red with no errors found?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm new to vscode... I accepted something for source control and then I believe all my files in android studio went red... not 100% sure that's why, I was also just starting to use firebase and firestore for the first time, so something may have gone wrong there... I tried changing the theme in android studio and that didn't work. And I'm not sure I should change file status colors... how can I revert back to normal?

[image: source control]

[image: android studio]

[image: file status colors]

Edit: followed this deleted answer by running `git add .` in the terminal, now my files are green(less frightening). Still don't really understand why...

[image: deleted question]

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal thing when you have files in a version controlled directory but the files are untracked. If this is a problem to you then try:

1. Add the files to the ignore file (.gitignore if you are using git)
2. Move the project out of repo in vcs.

Comment: How do I move my project out of repo and in vcs?